# Кнопка выходит за блок

Tags: html, css, url

Всем привет, образовалась проблема на мобилках. Блок-ссылка отображается неправильно.

Возможно ли как-то исправить этот баг прописав стили прямо на объекте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<a class="get_money pulse-button">Оплата изготовления визиток 1000</a>
```

Comment: Тебя не смущает, что ты пытаешься 200л воды уместить в десятилитровое ведро?

Comment: И кто сказал что это `БАГ`?  Как сверстал, так и выглядит...

Comment: Покажите ваши файлы `.html` и `.css` которые вы написали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от того, как именно вы хотите исправить баг.

Если можно переносить слова в кнопке - то

```
.get_money.pulse-button {white-space:normal; width:auto; text-align:center;}
```

Если нельзя - придется уменьшить шрифт, например:

```
.get_money.pulse-button {font-size:0.5em;}
```

Если напишете подробнее, что именно можно ,а что нельзя, и приведете кусок кода - можно будет сказать точнее.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте **display: inline;** или **word-wrap: break-word;**